# How to allow continuation of program processing where it was stopped by other thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, architecture

I hope my question is reasonable!

Let say 20 threads(using ThreadPool) executing `ValidateItem` method.

```
_validators = new Validators[] { new Validator1(), new Validator2(), ..., new ValidatorN() };

private void ValidateItem(string item)
{
     var req = new ValidationRequest(item);
     foreach (var validator in _validators)
     {                
           //------(1)    
           res = validator.Validate(req);
           OnValidatorCompletedEvent(item, res);
           if (res.Type == ValidationResultType.Invalid)
           {                       
                        break;
           }
     }
     OnAllValidatorsCompletedEvent(item, res);                 
}
```

Before starting validation of specific validator it should be checked whether that validator is ready. If it's not and not timed-out it should retry later. I thought to add the following code in **(1)**

```
while(!validator.IsReady && !(timedout > 5000))
{
    Sleep(200);
    timedout += 200;
}
```

but all 20 threads can stuck here, for example on `Validator10`, and thus all 20 threads will wait instead of, meanwhile, continue validating other items at least for `Validator1` to `Validator9`.
So, how could I allow continuation of validating other items at least for `Validator1` to `Validator9` and when `Validator10` become ready it will continue where it was sopped?

Comment: In your design, all threads are running all validators?

Comment: I a little bit don't understand what you mean. Each thread executes `ValidateItem`, so each thread will execute `_validators` list

Comment: Are you saying that when the first thread hits a `!validator.IsReady` condition, and goes into `Sleep` then at that point it's holding up all the other threads, even if they are not on that same validator? Invoking `Sleep` on one thread shouldn't block others. Can you include your code starting the background threads?

Comment: Are you talking about threaded producer-consumer collection? Take a look at [BlockingCollection<T>](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_BlockingCollectionT), or any other more suited for your task.

Comment: @GuthMD, let say Validator10.IsReady will be true after 2min(it depends on some external condition). So, 1st thread hits Validator10.IsReady and it now in while loop. 2nd thread also hits Validator10.IsReady and also now in while loop and so on till last thread (20th). So if all 20 threads will hit Validator10.IsReady within, 10 sec for example, so we get 20 threads in their loops for 1min50sec.

Comment: Do the validators have to run in order? If so, it sounds like it is behaving as expected, and you're hitting a limitation of the design. From your code snippet, Validators 1-9 should have completed by the time waiting on 10 happens, so there's not much else to do, unless you can re-queue 10 to happen after 11+.

Comment: @GuthMD, you are right. How I accept your answer?

Comment: There's not really an answer, as the program is doing as designed. We just need to wait for admins to Close the question.